# How to change a dependency version in npm

Tags: npm, handlebars.js, gulp

I'm actually trying to use gulp-handlebars but I need to change handlebars version in the gulp-handlebars package. I can't find a way to do that with a command line, and I'm new to all of this stuff, so I'm asking for clear help, what files do I have to change ?

I assume that copy/paste of my good version of Handlebars in the gulp-handlebars folder wouldn't be enough (and I actually tried that).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [`gulp-handlebars`](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-handlebars/blob/master/index.js) is incredibly simple.  It should be fairly simple to use `handlebars` and [`vinyl-map`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/vinyl-map/) without relying on a plugin, something like:

In the terminal:

```sh
$ npm remove gulp-handlebars
$ npm install --save-dev handlebars@version-you-want vinyl-map gulp-rename
```

In your `gulpfile.js`:

```js
var handlebars = require('handlebars'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    map = require('vinyl-map');

// ... in your task ...

return gulp.src(...)
    .pipe(map(function(contents) {
        return handlebars.precompile(contents.toString() /*, options */);
    })
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.js' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(...));
```

I haven't test this, but it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I sense a solution coming in my way ... But there's still a minor issue that need to be solved with this solution. The file generated by my gulp task with the code you provided (which is good by the way) and the file generated through command `handlebars <input> -f <output>` is not the same, therefore things don't work as expected. It looks like it comes from an option sent to `handlebars` : -s in the terminal. I can't find any example of how to pass options with the code you provided, could you give me a hand on this ?

Comment: There's a space for options above.  I don't know anything about handlebars options, though. Check out the [handlebars website/manual/source code](https://npmjs.org/package/handlebars).

Comment: Can't manage to find the correct way to tell options, i'm still searching. Even if it doesn't fit my long term needs, you answered my question perfectly, so here's my approval. I'll edit if I find how to declare options. Thanks.